# How can I append specific pages from one pdf to another pdf?

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I have code which combines pdfs together. 
It takes all pages from each file I specify in Column A3:A5 and appends to A2.

Lets say all my pdfs have 5 pages each. However what If I want to only take the first 3 A3, and full 5 pages of A4, and 1 page A5?

Also I don't need to specify in between pages, ie 2 , 4 and 5 of A3.
It will always be in order, ie 1-3 or 1-5 or 1-2.

I have a counter that gets the number of pages already

```
  Dim i As Long, pgnumber As Range
    For Each pgnumber In Range("A2:A100")
    If Not IsEmpty(pgnumber) Then
    i = i + 1
    AcroDoc.Open pgnumber
    PageNum = AcroDoc.GetNumPages
    Cells(pgnumber.Row, 4) = PageNum
    End If
    AcroDoc.Close
    Next pgnumber
```

**full code:**

```
Sub main3()

    Set app = CreateObject("Acroexch.app")

    Dim FilePaths As Collection
    Set FilePaths = New Collection
    Dim AcroDoc As Object
    Set AcroDoc = New AcroPDDoc

    'Counts # of pages in each pdf, loads to column D.

    Dim i As Long, pgnumber As Range
    For Each pgnumber In Range("A2:A100")
    If Not IsEmpty(pgnumber) Then
    i = i + 1
    AcroDoc.Open pgnumber
    PageNum = AcroDoc.GetNumPages
    Cells(pgnumber.Row, 4) = PageNum
    End If
    AcroDoc.Close
    Next pgnumber


    'Append to this file, ideally will be a front page to append to, commented out for now.

    'FilePaths.Add "\path\name\here"

    'Active or not feature in Column B, Specify Yes to include in combination, no to exclude

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("A2:A100")
    If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 <> "No" Then FilePaths.Add cell.Value2
    Next cell


    'Combine files which are listed in Column A.

    Set primaryDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    OK = primaryDoc.Open(FilePaths(1))
    Debug.Print "PRIMARY DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

    For colIndex = 2 To FilePaths.Count
        numPages = primaryDoc.GetNumPages() - 1

        Set sourceDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        OK = sourceDoc.Open(FilePaths(colIndex))
        Debug.Print "(" & colIndex & ") SOURCE DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

        numberOfPagesToInsert = sourceDoc.GetNumPages

        OK = primaryDoc.InsertPages(numPages, sourceDoc, 0, numberOfPagesToInsert, False)
        Debug.Print "(" & colIndex & ") PAGES INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY: " & OK

        Set sourceDoc = Nothing
    Next colIndex

    OK = primaryDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, FilePaths(1))
    Debug.Print "PRIMARYDOC SAVED PROPERLY: " & OK

    Set primaryDoc = Nothing
    app.Exit
    Set app = Nothing
    MsgBox "DONE"
End Sub
```

Any help on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

**Tried the below code, but it doesn't have any effect:**

```
'attempt to do start and end page in col E and F.

    startPage = Range("E" & colIndex)
    endPage = Range("F" & colIndex)
    OK = sourceDoc.DeletePages(1, startPage - 1)
    OK = sourceDoc.DeletePages(endPage - startPage + 2, sourceDoc.GetNumPages)
```

Comment: The problem you're having might be related to the fact that `colIndex` does not correspond to a row in the range. Since, presumably, there are some "No" values in column B, then `FilePaths.Count` will be less than the number of rows in the range. The first time you skip a "No" row, your `colIndex` will be pointing to the skipped row. Each skipped row after will throw you off even further. In short, you are not necessarily pulling `startpage` and `endpage` from the correct row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is a More Nearly Complete Answer Below**

See my comment on your question. If that is accurate, this may fix the problem:

Add:

```
Dim FileRows As Collection
Set FileRows = New Collection
```

Change

```
If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 <> "No" Then FilePaths.Add cell.Value2
```

To:

```
If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 <> "No" Then
    FilePaths.Add cell.Value2
    FileRows.Add cell.Row
Endif
```

Change:

```
startPage = Range("E" & colIndex)
endPage = Range("F" & colIndex)
```

To:

```
startPage = Range("E" & FileRows(colIndex))
endPage = Range("F" & FileRows(colIndex))
```

---

**More Nearly Complete Answer**

Okay, I know I shouldn't do this, but here we go. I have revised your code to work the way I think it should work. It is not a complete revision, because the whole thing *could* be doing in one pass and the Collection objects *could* be eliminated. There may be bugs in the following code, because I don't have the Adobe Acrobat SDK. But, I think it gets you closer than you were and it puts everything in place. You should be able to do any debugging from here:

```
Sub CompileDocuments()

    Dim acroExchangeApp as Object   ' Needed because?
    Dim filePaths As Collection     ' Paths for PDFs to append
    Dim fileRows As Collection      ' Row numbers PDFs to append
    Dim fileIndex as Long           ' For walking through the collections
    Dim acroDoc As AcroPDDoc        ' Manages imported PDFs
    Dim sourceDoc as Object         ' Manages imported PDFs (Same as above?)
    Dim primaryDoc As Object        ' Everything gets appended to this
    Dim importPath As Range         ' Cell containing a PDF to append
    Dim pageCount As Long           ' Total pages in an appendable PDF
    Dim insertPoint as Long         ' PDFs will be appended after this page in the primary Doc
    Dim startPage as Long           ' First desired page of appended PDF
    Dim endPage as Long             ' Last desired page of appended PDF  

    ' Initialize
    Set filePaths = New Collection
    Set fileRows = New Collection
    Set acroDoc = New AcroPDDoc
    Set acroExchangeApp = CreateObject("Acroexch.app")
    Set primaryDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

    ' Pass through rows setting page numbers and capturing paths
    For Each importPath In Range("A2:A100")

        ' Put the page count of each PDF document in column D
        If Not IsEmpty(importPath) Then
            acroDoc.Open importPath
            pageCount = acroDoc.GetNumPages
            importPath.OffSet(0,3) = pageCount
            acroDoc.Close
        End If
        Set acroDoc = Nothing

        ' Remember which documents to append and the row on which they appear
        ' Skipping any rows with "No" in column B
        If importPath.Offset(0, 1).Value2 <> "No" Then
            filePaths.Add importPath.Value2
            fileRows.Add  importPath.Row
        End If

    Next importPath

    ' Combine all file listed in Column A.
    ' Start by opening the file in A2.
    OK = primaryDoc.Open(filePaths(1))
    Debug.Print "PRIMARY DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

    ' Loop through the remaining files, appending pages to A2
    ' Note that columns E and F define the desired pages to extract from
    '   the appended document.

    For fileIndex = 2 To filePaths.Count

        ' Pages will be added after this insert point
        insertPoint = primaryDoc.GetNumPages() - 1

        ' Open the source document
        Set sourceDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        OK = sourceDoc.Open(filePaths(fileIndex))
        Debug.Print "(" & fileIndex & ") SOURCE DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

        ' Get start and end pages
        startPage = Range("E" & CStr(fileRows(fileIndex))).Value
        endPage = Range("F" & CStr(fileRows(fileIndex))).Value

        OK = primaryDoc.InsertPages(insertPoint, sourceDoc, startPage, endPage-startPage+1, False)
        Debug.Print "(" & fileIndex & ") " & endPage-startPage+1 & " PAGES INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY: " & OK

        Set sourceDoc = Nothing

    Next fileIndex

    OK = primaryDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, filePaths(1))
    Debug.Print "primaryDoc SAVED PROPERLY: " & OK

    Set primaryDoc = Nothing
    acroExchangeApp.Exit
    Set acroExchangeApp = Nothing

    MsgBox "DONE"

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks but Im not getting any effect of this, its still combining all pages. ie for my 2nd file (16 pages) I put 1 in col E and 5 in col F. Should append 5 to my main file, instead appended all 16. Why did you change the `if` part?  That was to do whether to skip over the file or not.

Comment: @excelguy I changed the `if` because I wanted to do two things instead of one. FileRows keeps track of the row on which the un-skipped path appears. Rows marked with "No" in column B will still be skipped. I suspect that you are not seeing a difference because your first file is not skipped, and this wasn't the problem. Trust me, this would have been a problem later. :-)

Comment: @excelguy According to Adobe docs, it looks like your InsertPages call might need to be changed. Remove the line that sets the value of `numberOfPagesToInsert`. I think you can be done with that. Change your insert pages call to `OK = primaryDoc.InsertPages(numPages, sourceDoc, Range("E" & FileRow(colIndex)).Value, Range("F" & FileRow(colIndex)).Value, False)` and see if that fixes it. Here's a link to the docs I saw: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#rhhlterm=insert%20pages&rhsyns=%20&t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FIAC_API_OLE_Objects%2FInsertPages.htm

Comment: @excelguy Okay, check out my answer now.

Comment: Okay I commented out `Put the page count of each PDF document in column D` because it isnt really needed, this can be added later.  So now I am getting a `type mismatch` on `startPage = Range("G" & CStr(fileRows(fileIndex))).value` where I manually input my start page (I changed it to col G.)

Comment: Sorry , I am testing and it looks like I am getting somewhere with this :) , will keep you posted.

Comment: Glad to hear it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try deleting the unwanted parts of each pdf prior to appending them all together with `sourceDoc.DeletePages(startPage, endPage)` for example:

```
OK = sourceDoc.Open(FilePaths(colIndex))

startPage = Range("C" & colIndex)
endPage = Range("D" & colIndex)
OK = sourceDoc.DeletePages(1, startPage - 1)
OK = sourceDoc.DeletePages(endPage - startPage + 2, sourceDoc.GetNumPages) ' just some arithmetic

Debug.Print "(" & colIndex & ") SOURCE DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK
```

You would just need to specify `startPage` and `endPage` for each in columns C & D... or you can change this snippet and specificy them however you prefer

Comment: Thanks Kubie, going to test it. Where in the code should this be placed?

Comment: You can put the middle 4 lines below `OK = sourceDoc.Open(FilePaths(colIndex))` and above `Debug.Print "(" & colIndex & ") SOURCE DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK`

Comment: ok I did that, but getting red text. `compile error: Expected =`

Comment: @excelguy Hmm, just made an edit to the answer, I believe we need to add the `OK = ` before those 2 lines

Comment: Hmm didnt seem to work. my file in A2 had 28 pages after running has 43, A3 has 15 pages, In Col E2 I have 1 and F2 I got 28, then in E3 I put 1 and F3 I put 10. I was expecting file in A2 to have 38 pages not 43.

Comment: I am not able to test as I don't have the adobe plugin so not sure what to say...maybe use some breakpoints in that area to double check. Also just wanted to clarify that the code in the answer looks for page numbers in Columns C & D, I saw you mentioned E & F

Comment: @excelguy sidenote: you should always specify your worksheet your grabbing data from with `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(..).Range(..)` instead of `Range(..)`

Answer (score 1):

**EXPLANATION:**

For First Code I removed everything but the barebones: filepath to the doc being appended to and filepaths to the file that we are getting the pages that are to be appended into primary doc.

I set up a constant for us and set it to 2. We can set it to 3 or 5 etc. This constant will be passed in the PAGE TO END part of the insertpage function. I have a feeling that you are going to say that there is some relationship between total num of pages in a pdf and the num to append, but this is not clear from OP

**BREAKING DOWN INSERTPAGES():**

INSERTPAGES(the page number where insertion starts (inside primaryDoc), a path to the PDF that is the source of the insertion pages (sourcedoc pathway), page to start from (sourceDoc), page to end (sourceDoc), true or false whether books are inserted too

**CODE BAREBONES:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AppendPDF()
Dim app                             As Object
Dim acroDoc                         As Object
Dim filePaths                       As Collection
Dim pathwayIterator                 As Range
Dim primaryDoc                      As Object
Dim OK                              As String
Dim numPages                        As Long
Dim colIndex                        As Long
Dim sourceDoc                       As Object
Const finalPage = 2

    Set app = CreateObject("Acroexch.app")
    Set acroDoc = New AcroPDDoc
    Set filePaths = New Collection

    For Each pathwayIterator In Range("A2:A100")
        If pathwayIterator.Value <> "" Then
            filePaths.Add pathwayIterator.Value2
        End If
    Next pathwayIterator

    Set primaryDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    OK = primaryDoc.Open(filePaths(1))
    Debug.Print "PRIMARY DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

    For colIndex = 2 To filePaths.Count
        numPages = primaryDoc.GetNumPages() - 1

        Set sourceDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        OK = sourceDoc.Open(filePaths(colIndex))
        Debug.Print "(" & colIndex & ") SOURCE DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

        OK = primaryDoc.InsertPages(numPages, sourceDoc, 0, finalPage, False)
        Debug.Print "(" & colIndex & ") PAGES INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY: " & OK

        sourceDoc.Close
        Set sourceDoc = Nothing
    Next colIndex

    OK = primaryDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, filePaths(1))
    Debug.Print "PRIMARYDOC SAVED PROPERLY: " & OK

    Set primaryDoc = Nothing
    app.Exit
    Set app = Nothing
    MsgBox "DONE"
End Sub
```

**CODE EXTRA:**

Here we added a bit more. I am not sure what you are doing with the file lengths, I have a feeling that you are going to link them with the number of pages to append. Here we make two collections, one with pathways to the files we are working with a second holds the number of pages of each of these files

```
Option Explicit

Sub AppendPDF()
Dim app                             As Object
Dim acroDoc                         As Object
Dim filePaths                       As Collection
Dim pgnumber                        As Range
Dim pageNum                         As Long
Dim FileNumPages                    As Collection
Dim pathwayIterator                 As Range
Dim primaryDoc                      As Object
Dim OK                              As String
Dim numPages                        As Long
Dim colIndex                        As Long
Dim sourceDoc                       As Object
Const finalPage = 2

    Set app = CreateObject("Acroexch.app")
    Set acroDoc = New AcroPDDoc
    Set filePaths = New Collection

    'Counts # of pages in each pdf, loads to column D.
    For Each pgnumber In Range("A2:A100")
        If Not IsEmpty(pgnumber) Then
            acroDoc.Open pgnumber
            pageNum = acroDoc.GetNumPages
            Cells(pgnumber.Row, 4) = pageNum
        End If
    acroDoc.Close
    Next pgnumber

    'Append to this file, ideally will be a front page to append to, commented out for now.

    'FilePaths.Add "\path\name\here"

    'Active or not feature in Column B, Specify Yes to include in combination, no to exclude
    Set filePaths = New Collection
    Set FileNumPages = New Collection

    For Each pathwayIterator In Range("A2:A100")
        If pathwayIterator.Value <> "" Then
            filePaths.Add pathwayIterator.Value2
            FileNumPages.Add Cells(pathwayIterator.Row, 4)
        End If
    Next pathwayIterator

    'Combine files which are listed in Column A.

    Set primaryDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    OK = primaryDoc.Open(filePaths(1))
    Debug.Print "PRIMARY DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

    For colIndex = 2 To filePaths.Count
        numPages = primaryDoc.GetNumPages() - 1

        Set sourceDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        OK = sourceDoc.Open(filePaths(colIndex))
        Debug.Print "(" & colIndex & ") SOURCE DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

        OK = primaryDoc.InsertPages(numPages, sourceDoc, 0, finalPage, False)
        Debug.Print "(" & colIndex & ") PAGES INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY: " & OK

        sourceDoc.Close
        Set sourceDoc = Nothing
    Next colIndex

    OK = primaryDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, filePaths(1))
    Debug.Print "PRIMARYDOC SAVED PROPERLY: " & OK

    Set primaryDoc = Nothing
    app.Exit
    Set app = Nothing
    MsgBox "DONE"
End Sub
```

Comment: I get `object doesnt support this property or method` on `primaryDoc.Select` , also why do you have the stops in there? Btw file page lengths arent needed, it was kind of an extra I added. However in col G and H I want to specify start and end pages, then these will append to the file. For example a file may contain 16 pages but only want to include 1 to 3.

Comment: just forgot to remove the .select & stops. was just experimenting. So the range of pages to include changes from file to file? Here I assumed that you are always starting from page 1 and ending on same page, so I set end page as a constant. In example I set to 2, you can change.